# Ext JS: Filtering the store

Tags: extjs

I am running a weird reg ex issue. I am trying to filter the names starts with character A or a and use
dataStore.filter("name", /^[Aa]*$/);

But for some reason, I get empty store.

Any help is appreciated

Tharahan

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is wrong. You're asking for the beginning of the string followed by any number of the letter a followed by the end of the string. The only things that will match are the empty string and string like A, a, Aa, aAAaaAaaaAAaa, etc.

Try this:

```
dataStore.filter('name',/^[Aa]/)
```